# Differece beetween git merge and in github pull request

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am only starting to work with git hub. I will be very thankful for help with my question.I can't understand difference between, git fetch -> git merge -> git push, which you do local in you computer and when you push you branch, than in github.com you create  pull request, and click merge. Maybe I do something wrong, and that is why i can't understand the difference. Sorry for this questions and thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull <remote> <branch>` is basically a `git fetch <remote>` followed by `git merge <remote>/<branch>`.

So a *pull request* is basically a request you submit to the owner of a GitHub repository, asking them to `git pull` your changes into their repository.

If you own the repository you're pushing to, you don't need to use a pull request unless you want to give other collaborators an opportunity to review your changes before you merge.

Answer (score 0):

you could start with a git tutorial: http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1